# Intersection of translates of a pair of trivially-intersecting subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, with subgroups $H,K \leq G$ such that $H \cap K = \{1_G\}$. Then can we say much in general about the intersections $Hk \cap Kh$ as $h$, and $k$ vary through $H$, and $K$ respectively?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to assume that the group is abelian. Let $Hg_1$ and $Kg_2$ be any two right cosets of $H$ and $K$ in $G$.

If $|Hg_1 \cap Kg_2| > 0$, then there exist $h\in H$, $k \in K$ with $hg_1=kg_2$. If we also have $h'g_1 = k'g_2$ with $h' \in H$, $k' \in K$, then $hh'^{-1} = kk'^{-1}$ and then $H \cap K = \{1 \}$ implies that $h=h'$ and $k=k'$.

We conclude that $|Hg_1 \cap Hg_2| = 0$ or $1$.

More generally, for arbitrary subgroups $H,K \le G$, $Hg_1 \cap Kg_2$ is either empty, or it is a coset of $H \cap K$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in Hk\cap Kh$, then there exists $h_1\in H$ and $k_1\in K$ such that $x=h_1k=k_1h$. If $G$ is abelian then we must have $h_1=h$ and $k_1=k$. Thus,

> If $G$ is abelian then we have $Hk\cap Kh=\{hk\}$.

I am not sure what to say when G is non-abelian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m going to leave the question open because I’m also interested in the non-Abelian case